# Mono<T> and Flux<T> as a parameter in function

Tags: java, project-reactor

What is the use case for `Mono<T>` and `Flux<T>` as parameter in function.

Code

```
Flux<String> findByLastName(Mono<String> lastname) {
   //implementation
}
```

When I invoke above method from rest, what will be difference from not using `String.class` as parameter?

Comment: It's the use case for using Mono/Flux combined with the use case for method parameters. What is it that you're really asking here? Do you know the use case for Mono/Flux?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt  i know use case for Mono/Flux in computation but i dont understand specifically using it as method parameter

Comment: _" what will be difference from not using String.class as parameter?"_ I assume mean what's the difference to using string. Using a string value implies that you (already) have a value. That doesn't have to be true for a `Mono`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first comment question:

> @ErwinBolwidt i know use case for Mono/Flux in computation but i dont understand specifically using it as method parameter – Bibek Shakya

When you use it as a parameter you have to deal with it as a stream (meaning you don't have it yet) so for example you should never say lastname.block(), because this means you've just blocked the thread until this value is available.

---

**Disclaimer Extra information**

If you're asking whether you should wrap anything from now on in a Mono or a flux, then of course not, because it adds unnecessary complexity to the method and the caller.

And for a design perspective, answer is simple, by asking basic questions:

- When to use a Mono in general ?

  - Well, when you still don't have the value.
- When to use Flux in general ?

  - Well, when you have a stream of data coming or not.

So we should not think of who is using the method and try to make the method convenient for him, but actually we should think of the method needs.

And a use case for that is when the method actually needs argument in this way; meaning you actually do stream processing inside, for example your method accepts an infinite stream of sensor data, and the method inside is going crazy like:

`Flux<Point> processSensor(Flux<Double> data){
    return data.filter(blabla).zipWith(blabla).map(...);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Where the `Mono<String> lastname` is coming from in the first place?

Imagine, you have another method, something like this:

```
Mono<String> findLastNameById(Long id) {
    // implementation
}
```

Now, if you have the method in your example, you can use it by passing a Mono as an input parameter:

```
Flux<String> findByLastName(Mono<String> lastname) {}

// Usage Mono as input parameter:
return findByLastName(
    findLastNameById(id)
);
```

However, it’s more idiomatic in reactive programming to avoid passing `Mono` or `Flux` as parameters. Instead, you should chain operations using methods like `flatMap`. So, the preferred usage would be:

```
Flux<String> findByLastName(String lastname) {}

// Use it like this:
return findLastNameById(id)
    .flatMap(this::findByLastName);
```

Answer (score -1):

Only use cases I can think of why a method parameter is `Mono<String> lastname`

1. Was retrieved from a WebClient/Router type function
2. [@Secured("ROLE_EVERYONE")](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-erms) was used in a previous method to retrieve the `lastname`

> For this to work the return type of the method must be a
>   org.reactivestreams.Publisher (i.e. Mono/Flux).